# Why add_menu_page adds admin.php and how to remove it?

Tags: admin-menu, add-menu-page

I'm trying to add custom menu items for my Custom Post Type.
I've added `"show_in_menu" => false` in my CPT definition so it will not show in admin menu.

Then I've added to admin_menu action:

```
add_menu_page('Example', 'Example', 'activate_plugins', 'edit.php?post_type=example', 'render_table', 'dashicons-tickets', 3);
add_submenu_page ( 'edit.php?post_type=example', 'All Examples', 'All Examples', 'activate_plugins', 'edit.php?post_type=example');
add_submenu_page ( 'edit.php?post_type=example', 'Add new Example', 'Add new Example', 'activate_plugins', 'post-new.php?post_type=example');
```

I would like to overwrite default menu for that CPT but links in menu look like this:

```
/wp-admin/admin.php?page=edit.php%3Fpost_type%3Dexample
/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=example&page=edit.php?post_type=example
/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=example
```

Because of this 2nd link does not lit up when I'am on listing page for that post type. Is there any way to make 1st and 2nd link look like this:

```
/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=example
/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=example
```

As it is in default menu? Maybe I need to overwrite their functions in some other way?